# Getting a String Instead of Array from Redshift while we dump data from DocumentDb to Redshift using Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark, aws-glue-workflow

I have data that has an array of strings in documentdb. But when I dump to Redshift using glue the whole array is treated as a string. I know that there is no direct way of converting into an array in Redshift but is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no array data type in redshift. The only thing you could do is to [explode](https://www.google.com/search?q=array%20explode%20pyspark&ei=0GKfYauXFI-U9u8P26SneA&ved=0ahUKEwirv53MpLP0AhUPiv0HHVvSCQ8Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=array%20explode%20pyspark&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEBMyCAgAEBYQHhATMggIABAWEB4QEzIICAAQFhAeEBMyCAgAEBYQHhATMggIABAWEB4QEzIICAAQFhAeEBMyCAgAEBYQHhATMggIABAWEB4QEzIICAAQFhAeEBM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BQgAEIAEOgYIABAWEB46CAgAEBYQChAeOgoIABAIEA0QHhATSgQIQRgAUL4FWKwJYMcKaAJwAngAgAFZiAGGBJIBATeYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) the array on the way to redshift.

Answer (score 0):

You can store you data as a Redshift “super” data type as a json list.  Would this help in your case?